# How to use HDF5 in Windows Java project with NetBeans

Tags: java, windows, hdf5

I have a simple Java project and I have to write some data to a HDF5 file. I use Netbeans under Windows. Normally, I build libraries from the respective jar-files. So much for my knowledge how to do things ;)

I downloaded and installed the binaries from [the hdf5 download page](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/). But what comes next? I had a look at [HDF5-Java support page](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/support/HDF-Java) but did not get any clue what to do to integrate HDF5 in my JavaApplication.

P.S.: I found [sis-jhdf5](https://wiki-bsse.ethz.ch/display/JHDF5/Download+Page) but I did not get it running as well. I also found some older sites explaining the [compilation of HDF under windows](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/HDF-JAVA/HDF-JAVA-2.5/src/build_src_windows.html) and a thread for [OS_X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374616/getting-started-with-hdf5-java-library) but that did not help me either.

There are so many different pages trying to explain this matter and I somehow lost the overview. May someone help me, please? A higher level of detail in the explanation would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not obliged to use a specific Java HDF5 library, you may want to have a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) which greatly simplify how HDF5 files are handled. This tool can be used in NetBeans IDE (8.2) as follows:

1. Download HDFql from http://www.hdfql.com/#download and unzip it.
2. Open NetBeans.
3. Select menu option `File > New Project` (a dialog titled `New Project` should pop-up).
4. Inside dialog `New Project`:

   4.1. Select `Java` for the category and `Java Application` for the project.

   4.2. Press button `Next`.

   4.3. Specify a name for the project and its location.

   4.4. Press button `Finish`.
5. Select menu option `Run > Set Project Configuration > Customize` (a dialog titled `Project Properties - ...` should pop-up).
6. Inside dialog `Project Properties - ...`:

   6.1. On the left side of the dialog, select `Sources` for the category, and after:

   6.1.1. Press button `Add Folder...` in the `Source Packages Folders` (a dialog titled `Add Source Folder` should pop-up):

   6.1.1.1. Inside dialog `Add Source Folder`, select the folder where the HDFql Java wrapper was unzipped in step 1. Example: `c:\hdfql-2.0.0\wrapper\java`.

   6.2. On the left side of the dialog, select `Run` for the category, and after:

   6.2.1 On the `VM Options` field, insert `-Djava.library.path=c:\hdfql-2.0.0\wrapper\java\as\hdfql`.

The NetBeans project is now properly configured to use HDFql. Now, if you run the following Java program (as an example):

```
import as.hdfql.*;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create an HDF5 file named "test.h5"
        HDFql.execute("CREATE FILE test.h5");
    }
}
```

An HDF5 file named `test.h5` will be created in the folder where this program ran.

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is an option. And is there also a possibility to use the HDF object package described here: https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdf-object/use.html ? I guess this would be the easiest way for me to integrate hdf into my tool. Unfortnunately the steps described in the link do not work for me